# SELECT Data FROM CURSOR of PACKAGE, print it

Tags: sql, oracle, select, fetch, database

I want to print data of `Cursor_pkg.c1.row_emp`, for ex:`Cursor_pkg.c1.row_emp.last_name` that would be exist in `Cursor_pkg.row_emp` after `Cursor_pkg_func.Print_Cur` procedure would work. How can I do it?

1. I create PACKAGE with cursor and rec
2. I create PACKAGE with procedure that fetch cursor data in rec
3. I want to output fetched data. How?

There is two questions: I want to output data from package `emp_rec` (row) and I want to output it directly from PACKAGE `Cursor_pkg_func` procedure
P.S. The main idea is storing data and procedure/function for fetching and selecting data

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Cursor_pkg AUTHID DEFINER IS
        CURSOR C1 IS
            SELECT last_name, job_id FROM employees
            WHERE job_id LIKE '%CLERK%' AND manager_id > 120
            ORDER BY last_name;
        row_emp C1%ROWTYPE;     
    END Cursor_pkg;
    /

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Cursor_pkg_func IS
PROCEDURE Print_Cur;
END Cursor_pkg_func;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Cursor_pkg_func IS
    PROCEDURE Print_Cur IS
    BEGIN
        OPEN Cursor_pkg.C1;
        LOOP
            FETCH Cursor_pkg.C1 INTO Cursor_pkg.row_emp;
            EXIT when Cursor_pkg.C1%NOTFOUND;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(Cursor_pkg.row_emp.last_name);
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE Cursor_pkg.C1;
     END;
END;
/

BEGIN 
Cursor_pkg_func.Print_Cur;
END;
```

But I want to select and print from Cursor_pkg.row_emp PACKAGE without created function.
And how to print not only last_name but all row?
Errors start with: What's wrong with last three statements?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Cursor_pkg_func IS
TYPE outrec_typ IS RECORD (
    var_char2  VARCHAR2(30)
  );
  TYPE outrecset IS TABLE OF outrec_typ;
  FUNCTION f_trans (p in number ) RETURN outrecset PIPELINED;
END Cursor_pkg_func;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Cursor_pkg_func IS
    FUNCTION f_trans (p in number) RETURN outrecset PIPELINED IS
    out_rec outrec_typ;
    BEGIN
        OPEN Cursor_pkg.C1;
        LOOP
            FETCH Cursor_pkg.C1 INTO Cursor_pkg.row_emp;
            EXIT when Cursor_pkg.C1%NOTFOUND;
        END LOOP;
        LOOP
        out_rec.var_char2 := Cursor_pkg.row_emp.last_name;
        PIPE ROW(out_rec);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(out_rec.var_char2);
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE Cursor_pkg.C1;
     RETURN;
     END f_trans;
END Cursor_pkg_func;
/

begin
Cursor_pkg_func.f_trans(5);
end;
/
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? or what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: You should investigate the DBMS_OUTPUT and UTL_FILE packages.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: Output to where? You have `dbms_output` already, so do you just need to `set serveroutput on`, if your client supports that? Or do you want to return a ref cursor that your client can handle (including just printing in SQL*Plus)?

Comment: SET SERVEROUTPUT ON is always on :)

Comment: I never use UTL_FILE because i did not know

Comment: I can use BEGIN Cursor_pkg_func.Print_Cur; END; to run procedure but I want print that records from  row_emp of Cursor_pkg PACKAGE

Comment: And how to print not only last_name but all row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined a pipelined function, and this is not the way to call it:

```
SQL> begin
  2  Cursor_pkg_func.f_trans(5);
  3  end;
  4  /
Cursor_pkg_func.f_trans(5);
*
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PLS-00221: 'F_TRANS' is not a procedure or is undefined
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored


SQL>
```

You need to use a TABLE() function.  Although then you will discover the bug in your code:

```
SQL>  select * from table(Cursor_pkg_func.f_trans(5))
  2   /

SMITH
SMITH
SMITH
''''
SMITH
SMITH
SMITH
SMITH
ERROR:
ORA-00028: your session has been killed



273660 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Note I had to kill that session from another session, otherwise it would still be running.  So let's simplify the function and get rid of that pointless second loop ....

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Cursor_pkg_func IS
    FUNCTION f_trans (p in number) RETURN outrecset PIPELINED IS
    out_rec outrec_typ;
    BEGIN
        OPEN Cursor_pkg.C1;
        LOOP
            FETCH Cursor_pkg.C1 INTO Cursor_pkg.row_emp;
            EXIT when Cursor_pkg.C1%NOTFOUND;
            out_rec.var_char2 := Cursor_pkg.row_emp.last_name;
            PIPE ROW(out_rec);
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE Cursor_pkg.C1;
     RETURN;
     END f_trans;
END Cursor_pkg_func;
/
```

.... then lo!

```
SQL> select * from table(Cursor_pkg_func.f_trans(5))
  2  /

VAR_CHAR2
------------------------------
ADAMS
JAMES
MILLER
SMITH

SQL>
```

---

> "When I add begin and end; select not work"

You have created a pipelined function.  Why did you do that?  The reason you ought to have done that was because you wanted a PL/SQL function which could be used in the FROM clause of a SELECT statement.  That is the use case for pipelined functions.  So putting the call into an anonymous PL/SQL block really doesn't make sense.

But anyway.

Please read the documentation.  It is quite comprehensive, it is online and free.  The pertinent section in the PL/SQL Reference is the chapter on Static SQL.  It makes clear that SELECT statements in PL/SQL must *always* fetch records into a variable of some description.  Anonymous PL/SQL blocks are just the same as stored procedures in this regard.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#i45320).

Comment: Thanks APC, My Question was because I try to learn by doing. There much more to learn but big thanks.

Comment: Before you discover bug I remade it to CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Cursor_pkg_func IS
    FUNCTION f_trans (p in number) RETURN outrecset PIPELINED IS
    out_rec outrec_typ;
    BEGIN
        OPEN Cursor_pkg.C1;
        LOOP
      FETCH Cursor_pkg.C1 INTO Cursor_pkg.row_emp;
   EXIT when Cursor_pkg.C1%NOTFOUND;
   out_rec.var_char2 := Cursor_pkg.row_emp.last_name;
   PIPE ROW(out_rec);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(out_rec.var_char2);
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE Cursor_pkg.C1;
  RETURN;
     END f_trans;
END Cursor_pkg_func;
/

Comment: BEGIN
select * from table(Cursor_pkg_func.f_trans(5))
END;
/ When I add begin and end; select not work